# 0 initialization of C++ built-in types

Tags: c++, performance, initialization, built-in-types

suppose I have this struct (or class, my question applies to both):

```
struct builtin 
{ 
    int a;
    int b; 
    builtin() : a(), b(0) { } 
};
```

I know that both a and b will be initialized to 0 by the constructor of builtin. 
My question is: Is one method faster than the other?

Comment: i think such micro optimisations arent needed and you should focus on the more complicated application logic optimisation

Comment: <kidding>a() is faster at first because you have one less character to type, but b(0) is faster after amortizing all the times you will read this line.</kidding>

Comment: For a difference of one character, I think this is worthwhile when you consider that built-in types initialization can be called thousand of times in a program.

Comment: @pboy: seriously, even if there was a difference, until you see that it is a bottleneck (have you measured?) you will spend more time trying to optimize than the time you will gain. Assume, just for the sake of discussion, that `a()` had no cost, and `b(0)` required a single assignment. Then it would get you 1 cycle, and current CPUs are able to do 3*10^9 of them per core per second.

Comment: Better again, how dumb are those people that write compilers and optimizers if they were not able to recognize that pattern in code and replace it for the fastest of the two?

Comment: True that this optimization would probably be easy for compiler writers but I prefer facts to assumptions. Assumptions are not always true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: no. The compiled code is identical.

Answer (score 7):

They do the same and take the same amount of time. Also, optimizations on this level are pointless until a profiler proves the opposite. Use what's more readable to you.

Comment: If it was faster, it would be useful for new code. I don't agree that optimizations that are almost free (one character difference) are pointless.

Comment: Optimizations that happen because of a one character difference, are already known by the compiler writers. They make it happen automatically. Trust your compiler!

Comment: @BoPersson: There's no need to rely on trust when you can write the most direct code yourself with one different character. It's no effort and a potential (though, yes, near-neglible) gain.

Comment: @Tomalak: IMO you should trust your compiler to produce good code, especially as a beginner. There is no reason to believe that you easily can find a small and obvious edit to idiomatic code, that the compiler writers have missed. Trust your compiler! :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in the resulting machine code, only in readability. Here, a is default initialized while b is set to a specific value.

Is that important to show in the source code? Chose the one that make most sense!